# Web2py Default Function / Controller Not Working

Tags: web2py

Here is what I have in web2py/applications/myapp/routes.py file (this was pre-loaded, just added the BASE argument):

```
from fileutils import abspath
from languages import read_possible_languages

possible_languages = read_possible_languages(abspath('applications', app))
#NOTE! app - is an application based router's parameter with name of an
#            application. E.g.'welcome'

routers = dict(
    app= dict(
        default_language = possible_languages['default'][0],
        languages = [lang for lang in possible_languages
                     if lang != 'default'],
    ),
    BASE= dict(
        default_application = 'myapp',
        default_controller = 'default',
        default_function = 'index',
    functions = ['my', 'functions', 'are', 'here'], 
               )
)
```

I'm routed to the welcome app when I visit 127.0.0.1:8000, and receive an index error when I visit  127.0.0.1:8000/function and 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/function. I reloaded routes. This is the only routes.py file that I have in my web2py directory.

Comment: Do you define `app` anywhere? If not, it should be replaced with the name of an actual application. It might help if you show the traceback you are getting.

Comment: I only get these errors when attempting to visit the site without the controller: "invalid controller (home/index)" or "invalid request". I noticed in the routes file this note: "To enable the file, 1. rename <web2py-root-dir>/router.example.py to routes.py.." I don't have a routes file in my root folder; only in my app folder. Do I need one in root as well? I really don't understand why the mapping isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when using an app-specific routes.py file, you must still have a routes.py file in the root /web2py folder, and you must use `routes_app` to specifying routing to the applications (see the "Application-Specific URL rewrite" section at the end of [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Pattern-based-system) of the documentation).

Second, when using the parameter-based rewrite system (i.e., when defining a `routers` dictionary), you do not need to bother with app-specific routes.py files at all. Instead, just use a single routes.py file in the /web2py folder and specify a separate key in the `routers` dictionary for each app that needs custom routing (the "BASE" key applies to all apps). (Technically, you can have app-specific routes.py files, but there's not much benefit over just keeping everything in the main routes.py file).

Finally, in your above routes.py file, you must either define the `app` variable somewhere (it should be the name of an app) or replace it with the name of an app.

Comment: Okay, when I remove the app-specific routes.py file and place it in the root folder (so still using parameter-based system) the app works. However, it doesn't know how to route to the admin. How do I access the admin? Also, can be a little more specific about how I can use the parameter approach to define custom mappings for multiple apps? If I have app1 at 127.0.0.1:8000, how do I access app2 while also defining it as a default app on another port? I can ask a second question to give you credit for the latter if you prefer.

Comment: I see nothing in your routes.py that would prevent access to admin. However, admin can only be accessed via HTTPS or local requests, so perhaps that is the problem. Hard to say without knowing more. Regarding your second question, have a look at the "domains" parameter, documented in the [example file](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/examples/routes.parametric.example.py). If you have further questions, it will probably be easiest to ask on the Google Group.